# Internet connection drops down gradually in LAN connection in Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: networking, network-manager, ethernet

After connecting LAN cable 2-3 minutes later I see a question mark in my LAN icon on the top right corner and then I am unable to browse anything. Videos on YouTube are also starting to buffer. But the download is still continuing. After reconnecting internet, I am able to browse for the next few minutes. I have erased the disk and reinstalled OS (Ubuntu 18.10) but it is still happening. please give me an easy solution so that I can apply it on my own.

[image: lspci]

[image: lshw -C network]

Answer (score 0):

I had also a similar problem. I could solve it by turning off IPv6. 
Please add

`net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1`

`net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1`

`net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1`

to

`/etc/sysctl.conf`

and then type the following command and press Enter on a command line

`sudo sysctl -p`

Next, please create a new file `/etc/rc.local` and add these contents

```
#!/bin/bash
# /etc/rc.local

# Load kernel variables from /etc/sysctl.d
/etc/init.d/procps restart

exit 0
```

and give the permission to execute to the file

```
chmod 755 /etc/rc.local
```

Comment: can you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: should I write this command in terminal?

Comment: should i put # in front of them

Comment: No. Please do not write it. Because it means comment out.

Comment: Did it work? Please tell me more information if it didn't work.

Comment: Till now it has not disconnected. Your suggestion was good, THANK YOU

Comment: You are welcome and I am glad for that:)

Comment: Hi, Sorry for disturbing again. I am facing the same problem but its time period is little large(15-20 minute). Please help me.

Comment: Can you show me the result of a command 'ifconfig -a'?

Comment: I am unable to upload it. It is 79 KB but...

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ll4xNBq3Hc5Zd-XoznZIJ24zDaZLDpCL/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please cheak in this drive link.

Comment: ipv6 is turned on again. Type 'sudo sysctl -p' one more time and show me the result again.

Comment: Here it is https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ADy_agDd2sb7VVDitovp3_ncr2b-EioE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry, I meant the result of 'ifconfig -a'

Comment: Please show me the result of 'ifconfig -a'

Comment: First, I apologize for the late response. Whenever I was running the command "sudo sysctl-p", I lost internet access. But by running this command I was able to disable ipv6. Please help me to resolve this otherwise I have to change my OS.

Comment: https://www.admintome.com/blog/disable-ipv6-on-ubuntu-18-04/
here is the solution. What we are trying to fix is a bug of Ubuntu.

Comment: If this also does not work, please tell me. I will check for more detail.

Comment: Till now I have not faced this problem again. Hope problem has been solved. Thank You very much for giving me your valuable suggestion.

Comment: You are welcome :)